# Heroku resque no worker

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, resque

I have succesfully queued a job, which I can see in resque web.

But the job is never executeted, just pending. I have 1 worker on my heroku app. In resque stats the workers are 0.

In lib/tasks/resque.rb:

```
require 'resque/tasks'

task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'

  Resque.after_fork do |job|
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end

end

desc "Alias for resque:work (To run workers on Heroku)"
task "jobs:work" => "resque:work"
```

Comment: Are are starting this 1 worker?

Comment: How do I start this 1 worker? I have tried `heroku run bundle exec rake jobs:work` but get an error. Don't know how to build task..

Comment: You state **I have 1 worker on my heroku app.**.  What does that mean?

Comment: @messick - Have 1 dyno and 1 worker for my heroku app.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell Heroku to start up your Resque workers via a `Procfile`.  This is where you put the command you would run locally, like `RAILS_ENV=Production QUEUE=* bundle exec rake jobs:work`

This gives the added benefit of testing you Heroku Resque setup locally by using the same `Profile` to start Resque workers with Foreman.

[Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/queuing-ruby-resque) is a link on the Heroku site that explains how to get that set up.

Comment: unfortunately I am using windows and therefor can only test on Heroku. Why can´t I get the 1 worker started by running this command in console: `heroku run bundle exec rake jobs:work`

Comment: Typo.. the file should be named resque.RAKE...works fine now.

Comment: No, `Procfile` is they way to do this, do not do it through a rake task.  I have a feeling that what you've done is started a Resque worker on one of your web dynos.  Even if it looks like it's OK, it's 100% against what Heroku wants you to do and can and will causes problems later.

Comment: How do I create this Procfile? What should it be named and where should it go?

Comment: It's all in the link I gave you in my answer.  But, the file is a text file named `Procfile` that sites in the root of your app. Inside the file would be:

`resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 bundle exec rake jobs:work`

Answer (score 0):

As @messick said you are require to execute resque workers registration with a Procfile, and just in case you dont really care of have set up enviroments just add these lines in your Procfile:

```
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 COUNT=1 QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work 
worker: bundle exec rake resque:work COUNT=1 QUEUE=*
```

If require a scheduler just add this line

```
scheduler:  bundle exec rake resque:scheduler
```

Comment: why do you need to declare both `resque:` and `worker:` in the procfile?

Comment: i meant to give more examples...in my case i do have a worker (a thread i exec in my page , this is just for loading my web site in pieces using angularjs) and a resque process (this will be automatically exec by using YML file props)